# correlation of log and sqrt of the same matrix

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

I have a dataframe `subs` containing 9 variables 
I want to get the correlation between the log and the square root of the variables.

So I first calculate the 2 matrices:

```
library(corrplot)

logs = log(subs)
sqroots = sqrt(subs)
```

Then I replace infinite values if any:

```
logs = do.call(data.frame,lapply(logs, function(x) replace(x, 
is.infinite(x),NA)))

sqroots = do.call(data.frame,lapply(sqroots, function(x) replace(x, 
is.infinite(x),NA)))
```

Then I use `corrplot` to plot the correlation matrix:

```
corrplot(cor(logs,sqroots, use = "complete.obs"), order = "AOE")
```

But it gives the error:

```
Error in e1 > 0 : invalid comparison with complex values
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help!

`subs`: https://pastebin.com/raw/y35FG2ZV

Comment: Pleas add data and libraries to your code!

Comment: if you are getting complex values out of your manipulation, it means you are taking the square root of negative numbers. But you cannot compare complex numbers with numerics when using corrplot

Comment: @FelipeAlvarenga `sqrt` and `log` only return a complex number if the input is complex. Compare `sqrt(-1)` and `sqrt(-1+0i)`.

Comment: yeah, you are right. Confused with matlab syntax here

Comment: @jaySf how can I add the data? you mean also the entire csv file?

Comment: @GioGio `dput(subs)`

Comment: Okay added thanks.
I also removed the `onlyNum` thing, now is just subs that is already without the non numerical fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is how you are trying to get rid of infinite values.
The following ought to solve your problem:

```
library(corrplot)

### Defining subs & onlyNum for the code to be reproducible###
subs <- matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
for(k in 1:5){subs[,k] <- sample(1:100, 5);rm(k)}
onlyNum <- 1:5

### To the answer ###
logs = log(subs[,onlyNum])
sqroots = sqrt(subs[,onlyNum])

### The 2 lines below should solve your issue ###
logs[which(is.infinite(logs), arr.ind = TRUE)] <- NA
sqroots[which(is.infinite(sqroots), arr.ind = TRUE)] <- NA

corrplot(cor(logs,sqroots, use = "complete.obs"), order = "AOE")
```

Here is the output yielded: [image]

---

**Update**

Now that that data has been provided, an edit is in order.

(1) As `subs` is a data frame and `is.infinite` has no implemented method for data frames, one would have to use `sapply(logs, is.infinite)` instead of `is.infinite(logs)` and respectively for `sqroots`.

(2) However, as indicated, the issue lies in `order = "AOE"`: "AOE" (Angular Order of the Eigenvectors) is only defined for real valued eigenvalues as it needs to check positiveness (c.f. `?corrMatOrder`). Computing the eigenvalues of the correlation matrix yields:

```
> eigen(cor(logs,sqroots, use = "complete.obs"))$values
[1] 2.35892882+0.0000000i 1.69884142+0.0000000i 1.16180544+0.0000000i
[4] 0.99435961+0.0176823i 0.99435961-0.0176823i 0.89281529+0.0000000i
[7] 0.32520739+0.0000000i 0.29605683+0.0000000i 0.05592473+0.0000000i
```

Therefore another Argument for `order` has to be chosen, e.g. `order = "FPC"` (First Principal Component).

Comment: I get Error in is.infinite(logs) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
I guess that is because it is a dataframe and not a matrix, what should I use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved my problem.
I needed to remove the parameter `order = "AOE"`
The reason is probably because the correlations among log and sqrt are not symmetric, hence it can not order them to find a pattern.

Thanks to everyone!